# Getting iLO logs for a specific period

Tags: hp-proliant, windows-event-log, ilo

I am fetching iLO event logs remotely using cpqlocfg.exe and script Get_iLO_Log.xml. But this gives complete event logs and there is no parameter that can be set to get the logs only for a  specific period. 
Is there a way to get logs for a specific period using cpqlocfg.exe and Get_iLO_Log.xml?

Comment: Why are you fetching ILO events? Don't you care about the host's information?

Comment: We need to figure out the number of iLO logins on all the servers on our network for some auditing purpose. Hence the need to get the event logs. I am able to get the hosts information anyway using other methods like WMI or other methods. Each time getting all the logs is huge problem.